# What's the difference between `document.createTextNode` and `new Text()`?

Tags: javascript, dom

Both create a new [Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) node. It seems that the only difference is the browser compatibility. Is there any other differences?

Comment: `new Text()` is a bit faster according to this https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/17024/0/createtextnode-vs-textcontent-vs-innertext-vs-append-vs

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that, according to the DOM standard, there's almost no difference:

> ```
> text = new Text([data = ""])
> ```
>
> Returns a new Text node whose data is data. [(link)](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-text-text%E2%91%A0)

> ```
> text = document . createTextNode(data)
> ```
>
> Returns a Text node whose data is data. [(link)](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-document-createtextnode%E2%91%A0)

except for the fact that the argument is optional for the constructor, but required for `createTextNode`. (Omitting the argument for `createTextNode` will throw.)

```js
new Text();
console.log('first line worked');
document.createTextNode(); // throws
```